# In Haskell, concat builds a list lazily but my own version with a twist, doesn't

Tags: optimization, haskell

I'm trying to make a relatively simple function that's almost concat but with a little twist. It's supposed to binary or together the last and first elements of each list and combine them in the process. I'm working to learn to write code that can take advantage of the Stream Fusion capabilities in Data.List.Stream

I checked that the concat in base does what is needed and builds the list lazily, however, this version I created doesn't. in the base, concat is specified as follows:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat = foldr (++) []

(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(++) []     ys = ys
(++) (x:xs) ys = x : xs ++ ys
```

Here's my code:

```
bconcat :: [[Word8]] -> [Word8]
bconcat = foldr1 bappend

bappend :: [Word8] -> [Word8] -> [Word8]
bappend as bs = init as ++ (last as .|. head bs) : tail bs
```

The question I have is, how do I write this so the list is built lazily? I even tried writing bappend by mimicing the (++) definition in base but it didn't make a difference.

At the moment, I use the following code, it works the way I want but the performance falls behind concat. Also, it uses explicit recursion which I'd like to avoid.

```
bconcat :: [[Word8]] -> [Word8]
bconcat (a:b:xs) = init a ++ bconcat ((bappend (last a) b):xs)
bconcat (a:[]) = a
bconcat [] = []

bappend :: Word8 -> [Word8] -> [Word8]
bappend !a bs = (a .|. head bs) : tail bs
```

So, the question I have is, how do I write this code so it builds the list lazily and without explicit recursion?

Thank you for your time.

**Edit:**

My primary interest, for the moment, is making clean, concise and understable code with the standard combinators. I'm still very much a beginner with functional thinking and would love to see a reasonably efficient way of putting them to use here.

Comment: I would guess, that the problem is, that you have to evaluate the whole first list before being able to or it together. IMHO there's no lazy evaluation possible.

Comment: There definitely is a way to make it build the resulting list lazily. concat succeeds at it and it does almost the same thing. Also, the last snippet I posted does do it the way I want. It just ca't reach the performance level of concat.

Comment: I see the difference, the first version OR's (last as) with the re

Comment: I see the difference, consider bconcat on [[1],[2],[4],[8,0]] which is [15].  The foldr1 computes (1 .|. head [14]) by first computing [14] = foldr1 [[2],[4],[8]] and so on.  The second version computes bappend [[3],[4],[8]] then bappend [[7],[8]].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition looks strict to me.  For instance, try evaluating

```
length $ bconcat [[1,2,3],[4,undefined,6]]
```

But you could be building up thunks for the .|. expression.  Perhaps you want to force that.

You could always fuse things yourself if they don't fuse well automatically:

```
 bconcat [] = error "bconcat: empty outer list"
 bconcat (xs:xss) = loop xss xs
   where loop [] ys = ys
         loop ((x:xs):xss) [y] = let z = x .|. y in seq z $ z : loop xss xs
         loop ([]:_) _ = error "bconcat: empty inner list"
         loop xss (y:ys) = y : loop xss ys
```

Comment: I'm not sure which of my definitions of bconcat you meant to try "length $ bconcat [[1,2,3],[4,undefined,6]]" with but it returns 5 in both cases, like I expected.

Comment: Thank you for the fused version of bconcat. That code truly flies. It's even faster than regular concat. The program I'm trying to optimize runs 40% faster with that one.

Comment: Ack, that is broken: "bconcat [[1],[2],[4]]" gives "[3*** Exception: /tmp/foo.hs:(5,9)-(8,41): Non-exhaustive patterns in function loop"

Comment: Yes, I fixed it for my own code by adding a special case for when the new list only has one element. It looks like this:
`loop ((x:[]):xss) [y] = let z = x .|. y in seq z $ loop xss [z]`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a typo, 'bapennd' should be 'bappend' in the first snippet.  And I think 'combine' in the last snippet should be 'bconcat'.

It does look like the first (foldr1 bappend) will be fairly lazy.  Could you elaborate on the lack of laziness?

As for needing both "init xs" and "last xs" at the same time, you might want a single traversal of xs:

```
let un [] = error "no last element"
    un (x:[]) = ([],x)
    un (x:xs) = let (ys,z) = un xs
                in (x:ys,z)
```

This has a different space and time trade-off.  If you always force the answer of bconcat in order then it is likely an improvement.  The "last xs" holds a reference to the head of the whole list and prevents xs from being garbage collected until it is forced.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the typoes. lack of laziness as in eating all the memory in my system, caused by having to make the whole string in memory before any other code can do anything with it. The whole idea is to have this program work in constant memory.

Comment: I tried using your function un for getting the head and tail at the same time but it ended up slowing the code. I suspect this has something to do with stream fusion optimization as I am using that. That "last xs" holding the reference does explain why I get a slight improvement in performance for making the first parameter to the bappend I'm using currently, strict.

Answer (score 2):

I can change the answer by augustuss to more closely match the original problem by writing:

```
bconcat2 [] = []
bconcat2 (xs:xss) = loop xss xs
  where loop [] ys = ys
        loop xss (y:[]) = gather xss y
        loop xss (y:ys) = y : loop xss ys
        loop (xs:xss) [] = loop xss xs
        gather [] z = [z]
        gather ([]:xss) z = gather xss z
        gather ((x:[]):xss) z = gather xss $! z .|. x
        gather ((x:xs):xss) z = let z' = z .|. x in z' : loop xss xs
```

The above ignores any empty internal lists.

Comment: Thank you, my current code doesn't need to handle empty internal lists but it could be useful for some other purpose.